# Changing badge count in Push Notifications with Expo in background and foreground

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I was looking into ways to send push notifications to a native app and reading the expo documentation, I got confused by two bits of information that seem to contradict each other.

> Notifications will appear in the system notification tray as you've
>   come to expect, and tapping them will ***open***/***foreground*** the app.

(source: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications)

But in the section 'why not expo'  it states :

> Expo apps don't support background code execution (running code when
>   the app is not foregrounded or the device is sleeping). This means you
>   cannot use background geolocation, play audio in the background,
>   handle ***push notifications in the background***, and more.

(source: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo)

That seems contradictory since 'foregrounding' or 'opening' an app implies that it was running in the background how I see it.

In the end I would like to change the notification badge of an app icon with this, but given this info it's not clear to me if this is possible ?   In IOS and Android ?

Comment: Good news the background code execution will be available in next SDK version!

Comment: **handle push notifications in the background** could mean handling [ios silent notificaitons](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently) or [FCM data only messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded), which allow execution of code without user opening the app by tapping the notification in system tray. Notificaiton badge is for normal notifications. So you should be able to do this without any **background** mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed *foregrounding* the app sounds as if the app was actively running in the background and could therefore run code, but as the documentation states, this is not **currently** feasible with Expo alone. This entails that changing the badge count while the app is in background cannot be done.

On the other hand, when the app is in foreground or the notification is being open, this becomes feasible according to [this table in the documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#listening-to-notification-events).

Setting an arbitrary badge count on iOS can be done with [`Notifications.setBadgeNumberAsync(number)`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#exponotificationssetbadgenumberasyncnumber), whereas for Android [the only option available](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#channelandroid) is to make the sent push notifications count towards the badge count for a given channel.

Comment: The "this table in the documentation" link is broken

Comment: [this table in the documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/sdk/notifications/) - search for "push was received when..."

Comment: Thanks for the addition @Oversteer, I actually fixed the broken link at the time :)

Answer (score 2):

remove notification badge count for android - `Notifications.dismissAllNotificationsAsync()`

[expo dismissAllNotificationAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#dismissallnotificationsasync-promisevoid)